# What is the tradeoff in replacing Java with Grails?

Tags: java, grails

Having used Java for some years already, we know what we are gaining by moving to Grails. The question is, what are we losing? Performance?

Appreciate your input / ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Grails is a web framework based on Groovy. What web framework were you using in Java? That seems relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy compiles to JVM bytecode just like Java. With Grails you end up with a .war file to run in your container just like Java.

Groovy has slower run-time performance to Java in most areas since it is a dynamic language.
You can have java code in your Grails app in addition to groovy code.

Answer (score 2):

- "we know what we are gaining by
  moving to Grails", but are you sure?
- Team experience Are you sure that the
  team "will get things done"
  easily+major customizations?
- New employees? Grails is not that
  much used in the enterprise
- Performance? Probably slower than
  Java
- etc.

@aem++

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest issue is not the technical, but the manpower/skill issue.

A quick (non-scientific) job search on a job portal reveals 5 jobs mentioning Grails, and 15 *pages* for Java. Obviously this doesn't cater for candidates wanting to learn Grails etc., but when you're replacing staff and looking for people to maintain it, I suspect either you'll have difficulty finding people, or you will have to spend time getting them up to speed (I know it compiles to bytecode, I know it has Java-like idioms but there's still that time to factor in).

Answer (score 0):

You lose the experience you made with programming for a long time in java. And you need to get used to new frameworks etc.

Comment: Groovy is syntactically very similar to Java. And has a lot of syntactic sugar that lets you do things in fewer lines than java.

It is not that hard for a Java programmer to get used to groovy. Since it is a dynamic language some things are a little different than a statically typed language like Java.

Comment: And you can call Java from Groovy and Groovy from Java.  And Grails is built on top of Spring and Hibernate, which is pretty common in Java web development.

Comment: Yes, it will take less than a week for a Java developer to be up to speed with Grails. I recommend the book "Beginning Groovy and Grails: From Notice to Professional" by Apress publishing. Can be had on amazon for very cheap used.